"Could not create `Blob`" while passing a prompt and PDF to Gemini API
I am trying to pass a prompt and a PDF file to the Google Gemini API. I followed all the documentation and for some reason I am still having issues.
Here is the code:
def get_vision_response(pdf_file):
    try:
        genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

        model = genai.GenerativeModel(
            model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
            system_instruction=[
                "You are a helpful transcriber that can accurately transcribe text from images and PDFs.",
                "Your mission is to transcribe text from the provided PDF file.",
            ],
        )

        pdf_part = Part.from_data(pdf_file, mime_type="application/pdf")

        prompt = "Please transcribe the text in this PDF document."

        full_content = [prompt, pdf_part]
        
        response = model.generate_content(full_content)
        
        return response.text
        
    except Exception as e:
        print("An error occurred during the model invocation")
        
        # Save the error message to a text file
        with open("error_log.txt", "w") as error_file:
            error_file.write(f"An error occurred: {str(e)}\n")

When I tried printing my error in the exception, it was filled with garbage characters, so I had to save it to a file. This is the header portion of my error:

An error occurred: Could not create Blob, expected Blob, dict or
an Image type(PIL.Image.Image or IPython.display.Image). Got a:
<class 'vertexai.generative_models.generative_models.Part'> Value:
inline_data {   mime_type: "application/pdf"   data:
"%PDF-1.7\n%\302\265\302\266\n\n1 0 obj\n<</Type/Catalog/Pages 2 0
R>>\nendobj\n\n2 0 obj\n<</Type/Pages/Count 1/Kids[669 0
R]>>\nendobj\n\n3 0 obj\n<</Filter/FlateDecode/Length
9963>>\nstream\nx\001\305\235\313\256t\307m\205\347\347)z\234\301Q\357[\200
\003+\201\221\241a\001\031\307Jd
\200\0238\377\373\003\371X\227E\262\252Z\323\3000$\365\256\033\271H\026k\025\367>\177\277\375\351\366\367\333\235\377=\266\375\366|\357\267\377\375\317\333\277\335\37

Does anyone know how to fix this?

It would be nice to have more information from that error message. Did it include a traceback?

Also, please provide a [mre]; this error isn't reproducible, in part because we don't know what pdf_file is.

no traceback, this error is produced in the exception block. pdf_file is a data object of a pdf file

Try removing the try/except stuff for now; it'll make it much easier to debug your program.

For a better support on this kind of error is important to know the context. Example: What's the code that is calling your function?
But here you have a working example:
https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/generative-ai/docs/samples/generativeaionvertexai-gemini-pdf#code-sample

In the current stage, it seems that PDF data can be directly used for generating content by Gemini API. Ref (Author: me) When that is reflected in a sample script for python, it becomes as follows.
In this case, the following steps are run.

Upload PDF data to Gemini and retrieve uri from the uploaded data.
Generate content with your prompt and the uri.

The base sample script of this is from my answer.
Sample script:
import google.generativeai as genai
import time

GOOGLE_API_KEY = "###" # Please set your API key.
pdf_file = "sample.pdf" # Please set your PDF file with the path.
name = "sample-name-1"

genai.configure(api_key=GOOGLE_API_KEY)

# Check uploaded file.
try:
    pdfFile = genai.get_file(f"files/{name}")
    print(f"File URI: {pdfFile.uri}")
except:
    print(f"Uploading file...")
    pdfFile = genai.upload_file(path=pdf_file, name=name, resumable=True)
    print(f"Completed upload: {pdfFile.uri}")

# Check the state of the uploaded file.
while pdfFile.state.name == "PROCESSING":
    print(".", end="")
    time.sleep(10)
    pdfFile = genai.get_file(pdfFile.name)

if pdfFile.state.name == "FAILED":
    raise ValueError(pdfFile.state.name)


# Generate content using the uploaded file.
model = genai.GenerativeModel(
    model_name="gemini-1.5-pro-latest",
    system_instruction=[
        "You are a helpful transcriber that can accurately transcribe text from images and PDFs.",
        "Your mission is to transcribe text from the provided PDF file.",
    ],
)
prompt = "Please transcribe the text in this PDF document."
print("Making LLM inference request...")
response = model.generate_content([pdfFile, prompt], request_options={"timeout": 600})
print(response.text)

When this script is run, the content is generated by using your prompt and PDF data.
Reference:

Prompting with media files

